# Document on SharePoint opens in "edit" mode only once

Tags: office-integration, edit

### Problem

Any document (docx) I open or create I am able to to edit it only once. The following attempts open the document in "Read-Only" mode. I am able to overwrite the document.
[image]

### I've tried the following

- Add the site to "Trusted Sites"
- Compatability Mode
- Sign-out of all accounts in office applications
- Add FSSHTTPOff DWORD to the registry
- Open the application from IE 11, 10 and 9
- Modified Protected View Options in the trust center

### These are some things I've noticed

- I am able to open it in "edit" mode once from each unique device
- I am able to open the same document in "edit" mode once using "https" and once using "http"

### Things you may like to know

- The site has both forms based and windows based authentication
- The site might have had its SQL database moved between servers